# Is "whomnot" a valid word, and if not, what is a valid alternative?

Tags: single-word-requests

It just struck me when writing a message, that I don't know of an analogue of "whatnot" for persons. Does such a word exist? If not, could a person hypothetically see about somehow creating it "officially", whatever that wouldn't mean?

Comment: *Whatnot* is typically used as in *There were plentiful supplies of food, drink, maps, tents, sleeping bags and whatnot laid on for the expedition*. *Whatnot* is a sort of "catch-all" of miscellaneous items which it is not deemed necessary to list individually. The equivalent use of *whomnot*, one assumes would be to say *We were joined by participants, their wives, husbands, boy-friends, girl-friends and whomnot...*. Somehow I don't see it catching on!

Comment: Google "whomnot," and you'll find there's no such word. Can you give an example of where you would want a word analogous to "whatnot" for people? And I'm not sure I understand your desire to "officially" create sch a word -- that's not how it works, unfortunately. You'd have to just start using it yourself, and see if it catches on.

Comment: Ariel had whatsits, [whosits](https://www.wordnik.com/words/whosit), & even thingamabobs galore, but helas no whomnots. Are you sure it's not/wouldn't be 'whonots', btw?

Comment: Well, it might be somewhat specific to my speech patterns(I absolutely abuse whatnot as well), and for an example, "Oh, it's commonly used by cooks, bakers, baristas and whomnot". As to whether it should not instead be "whonot"... I have no idea, although it definitely sounds worse, in my opinion.

Comment: I think in the U.S. we would say, "Oh, it's commonly used by cooks, bakers, baristas, whoever -- "

Comment: We're talking about _nonce terms_ here; _whatnot_ is one such. Except for the fixed phrase _whatnot shelf_, it's always used to mean 'various things that I can't/won't describe', and it often appears last in a list.

Comment: @ewormuth: Or ***whomever***. As in [*There's just you and my daughter, and whomever. **Not whomever, just you and my daughter.***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22you+and+my+daughter%2C+and+whomever%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) Sounds fine to me. Personally, I understand ***whatnot*** as "short" for ***whatever not?***, where the negation is optional anyway. But since no-one else does the same with ***who[m]not***, I wouldn't feel comfortable being the only one.

Comment: I'll bet you that 99% of people in ordinary conversation (the same arena in which you would say "whatnot") would say "whoever," not "whomever."  In formal writing, I probably wouldn't use either one.

Comment: @ewormuth I don't. Perhaps a majority would say *whoever* but more than one percent would say *whomever* - especially in Britain. [This](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whoever%2C+whomever&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhoever%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhomever%3B%2Cc0) seems to suggest that about six times as many people would say *whoever*. So *whomever* is far more than 1 percent. And I would suggest that the one-seventh of people who use *whomever* are a more literate strand of the population.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=whatnot&searchmode=none) says it's short for "what may I not say", i.e. everything else that you didn't already list.

Comment: @WS2, I was engaging in a little hyperbole.  But I think the percentage in the U.S. would be signifcantly less than in Britain.  And of course they're more literate.

Comment: @ewormuth If you say so. If you look at scholastic statistics, doubtless we are both far less literate than the South Koreans and the Singaporeans!

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer here, is: "et al." A short form of "et alia," Latin term meaning "and others." The equivalent of "etc." (et cetera) for persons, rather than things.